# How to programmatically get IMEI number in j2me

Tags: java-me, mobile, imei

I am working on the project where I have to make one login page where user enters IMEI number. Now I have to anagrammatically check whether such kind of IMEI exist or not.

Comment: If you still need help with this, please edit your original question.